# Need help in nested array need to find first same element and add their second element in a single array?

Tags: php, loops

I've an array with arrays of different values that I need to re arrange.

**Original Array**

```
$cars = [
  [2022, "Corolla"],
  [2022, "Toyota"],
  [2021, "Corolla"],
  [2021, "Toyota"],
  [2021, "Honda"]
];
```

**Expected Array**

```
$resultCars = [
  [2022, "Corolla", "Toyota"],
  [2021, "Corolla", "Toyota", "Honda"]
];
```

Comment: Recommendation pick one language, the one you're most familiar with, and only use that one language tag. State in the question you will accept help in other languages ig there's a good advantage. Only use multiple language tags when you're having a problem with interrop code or you need to compare the behaviours of two languages. Don't use more than two because the question usually becomes too broad.

Comment: Also show your work. Obviously what you've got won't work, you wouldn't be asking this question if it did, but it give us a baseline we can form answers around. Maybe you have a small mistake that can be fixed with a little tweak. Maybe you're way off track, but we can use the code to see where you diverged and attack the problem at the source. Show no work and there's not too much we can do for you. Plus don't underestimate the social importance of showing you have invested effort into the problem.

Comment: It would be great if possible in php also otherwise here's great response in JavaScript.

Comment: So, we're just missing Python and PHP solutions now. Unless you'd like to add more language requirements. How about COBOL, Fortran, Ada, LISP, Haskell, Pascal, BASIC, Tcl, Bash, and Perl...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JS:

```js
const Cars = [ [2022, "Corolla"], [2022, "Toyota"], [2021, "Corolla"], [2021, "Toyota"], [2021, "Honda"] ];

const res = Cars.reduce((a, [year, name]) => ((a[year] ??= [year]).push(name),a),{});

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it in Javascript:

```
ResultCars = Cars.reduce((carry, [year, make]) =>
{
    let item = carry.find(([existingYear]) => existingYear === year);
    if(item)
        item.push(make);
    else
        carry.push([year, make]);

    return(carry);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const cars = [
  [2022, "Corolla"],
  [2022, "Toyota"],
  [2021, "Corolla"],
  [2021, "Toyota"],
  [2021, "Honda"]
];
console.log(Object.entries(cars.reduce((a,[year,make])=>
  ((a[year]??=[]).push(make), a), {})).map(i=>i.flat()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach in C++:

```
vector<pair<int, string>> cars {
    {2022, "Corolla"},
    {2022, "Toyota"},
    {2021, "Corolla"},
    {2021, "Toyota"},
    {2021, "Honda"}
};

map<int, set<string>> resultCars;
for (const auto& c : cars)
{
    resultCars[c.first].insert(c.second);
}
```

As a full example ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EqK4KqP6x)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Input
    vector<pair<int, string>> cars {
        {2022, "Corolla"},
        {2022, "Toyota"},
        {2021, "Corolla"},
        {2021, "Toyota"},
        {2021, "Honda"}
    };

    // Index
    map<int, set<string>> resultCars;
    for (const auto& c : cars)
    {
        resultCars[c.first].insert(c.second);
    }

    // Output
    for (const auto& c : resultCars)
    {
        int year = c.first;
        const auto& names = c.second;
        cout << year << " : ";
        copy(names.begin(), names.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "));
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```